# ShrinkProtoResourcesAction Premature end of file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i'm not able to generate release APK. Getting the following Build error.

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkReleaseRes'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkProtoResourcesAction
   > ParseError at [row,col]:[21,1]
     Message: Premature end of file.
```

Not able to open or find `ShrinkProtoResourcesAction` file. Check `Proguard` file everything seems ok.
Also i'm able to generate `.aab` file but facing issue while generating `.apk` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, there was some empty xml been added which was causing the error.

Comment: Hello @Sam , I am facing similar issue. And I have some more than 500 files in drawable and layout folders. how to find exact issue? I have checked <?xml tag, no space or any character before this tag.

Comment: No, there was a file created with just <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>